# Class 'Spatie\YamlFrontMatter\YamlFrontMatter' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I need help. I installed Yaml-front-matter via composer, everything was good. But if I use this class in my project, I get this very strange error. Why laravel doesn't see this class?
I do not find a solution with google.

I tried commands: **php artisan optimize: clear**, **composer dump-autoload**
but they don't help.

Thanks in advance.

[screen to show the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J63n.jpg)

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: You tried `\Spatie\YamlFrontMatter\YamlFrontMatter::parseFile(...);`  ?

Comment: @MaikLowrey, I tried, it's useless. And it sounds silly, but I don't understand how to reply to specific comment. I am absolutely beginner on this site

Comment: @Nico Haase, In my IDE (PHPStorm) everything is good, no errors. My own classes are included correctly, the problem only with this YamlFrontMatter class. The project is very simple, it has a short code, it is a training project. I do this exercise: 
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch/episodes/12
and I don't know how to do next steps, because class not found

Comment: It would be good to get more details. maybe share us the part of your composer.json where the package is included. Or if you work with docker and so on.

Comment: Have you checked whether theses classes do really exists where you expect them (within the vendor folder)?

Comment: @Maik Lowrey, I don't work with Docker. Here is my all my composer.json file (it consists of one line):


 `{
    "require": {
        "spatie/yaml-front-matter": "^2.0"
    }
}`

Comment: @NicoHaase, sure, they really exist. If they don't exist, IDE highlights the error, but in this case everything is good.

Comment: If they do exist there, and were properly installed by Composer, I don't get why that error occurs. What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: @Nico Haase, I'm a little confused with the directories. I have a directory "domains" (OpenServer directory), in which I have all my projects. In this directory I also see directories: "vendor" and "composer.phar", and also the files "composer.json" and "composer.lock". In file "composer.json" I see only one line: `{     "require": {         "spatie/yaml-front-matter": "^2.0"     } }`. 
But in my project directory "laracasts_laravel" I also see file "composer.json", and it consists more information, but line above doesn't exist.
Could you please clarify - maybe I installed the package wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Nico Haase, I solve this problem. I installed the composer to my project directory ('domains->laracasts_laravel->composer.phar'), and everything was fine. IDE required class from another directory (from folder 'domains->composer.phar etc.'), so it was not a visible error, BUT after compiling an error 'class not found' occurs. 

Thanks a million for help!

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you made the composer command on your working directory! I opened a new console and ran `composer require spatie/yaml-front-matter` but I didn't realized I was doing it on the parent folder of my project. If so, just do a `cd your-project` and run the command again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace this**

```
$document = YamlFrontMatter::parseFile(resource_path('posts/my-fourth-post.html');
```

**with this**

```
$document = \Spatie\YamlFrontMatter\YamlFrontMatter::parseFile(resource_path('posts/my-fourth-post.html');
```

It works.

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/class-yamlfrontmatter-not-found-laravel-docker-composer

Answer (score 0):

I was following a laracasts tutorial and ran into the same issue because I had missed they went through installing the package at the start of the video. I resolved it by just running:

```
composer require spatie/yaml-front-matter
```

The docs helped me out with resolving this, as there are a few other YAML related front-matter packages out there too.

https://github.com/spatie/yaml-front-matter.